# Atmega328p Uploads via ISP but not bootloader

Tags: atmega328, bootloader, avr, avrdude, isp

I'm trying to upload a bootloader to my atmega328p on a custom pcb containing external oscillator at 16MHz. It is possible to upload program via ICSP pins using Arduino as ISP (Official Arduino Uno) but not possible to upload a bootloader. This pcb needs bootloader as it will be used via FT232RL interface.

I've tried to upload bootloader at 115200 baud rate but that did not read any device signature. Also exact definition of my IC is "ATMEGA328P-AU TQFP-32 8-bit 20MHz", if it helps.

P.S That exact definition says it is 20MHz but I suspect that's correct as I don't entirely trust that shop.

Thanks in advance

Upload log

```
Sketch uses 1626 bytes (5%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 192 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1856 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/cu.usbmodem14101 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/var/folders/9z/8cpdsm0518x0b85yx7n4y_0c0000gn/T/arduino_build_452635/sketch_dec06a.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/deniz/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem14101
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : Arduino
         Description     : Arduino
         Hardware Version: 3
         Firmware Version: 4.4
         Vtarget         : 0.3 V
         Varef           : 0.3 V
         Oscillator      : 28.800 kHz
         SCK period      : 3.3 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: reading input file "/var/folders/9z/8cpdsm0518x0b85yx7n4y_0c0000gn/T/arduino_build_452635/sketch_dec06a.ino.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (1626 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.27s

avrdude: 1626 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against /var/folders/9z/8cpdsm0518x0b85yx7n4y_0c0000gn/T/arduino_build_452635/sketch_dec06a.ino.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file /var/folders/9z/8cpdsm0518x0b85yx7n4y_0c0000gn/T/arduino_build_452635/sketch_dec06a.ino.hex:
avrdude: input file /var/folders/9z/8cpdsm0518x0b85yx7n4y_0c0000gn/T/arduino_build_452635/sketch_dec06a.ino.hex contains 1626 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.21s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1626 bytes of flash verified

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Bootloader log (P.S. all sync attempts happen at the same time)

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -cstk500v1 -P/dev/cu.usbmodem14101 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0xFD:m -Uhfuse:w:0xDE:m -Ulfuse:w:0xFF:m

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/deniz/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem14101
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x60
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x66
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x78
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1e
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x06
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x7e
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe6
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x80
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x98
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x80

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: Have you tried to "Burn Bootloader"? Because by default it uploads compiled sketch without bootloader (it can be changed in board settings to use hex file with bootloader too).

Comment: That output is from Burn Bootloader button specified in Arduino IDE. So is it possible to upload bootloader and sketch at the same time?

Comment: In the build direcotry there'll be another hex file like this: sketch_dec06a.ino.with_bootloader.hex (however can't remember where it should be set exactly)

Comment: Yep I found it. I'll be trying that one. Also will there be a problem with flashing sketch with bootloader without redefining fuse-bits?

Comment: Also if you can write your comment as an detailed answer I can approve if it works

Comment: And are you sure the first is really working? The programmer = arduino is usually bootloader. You should see that stk500v1 too if you are using "Upload Using Programmer" (programmer must be set to Arduino as ISP). Maybe you've just uploaded it directly into the arduino that should be an programmer instead (and removed that ArduinoISP sketch from it)

Comment: I've uploaded ArduinoISP sketch again and tried to upload only the sketch, with_bootloader and only bootloader but no luck. I've updated the upload log in the question. Seems like programmer can't read target's device signature. I've successfully uploaded the bootloader to two of the same PCBs but no luck on this one.

Comment: If you have time to look into this more deeply I can move this comment section to a chat. I would be very happy if it's possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101890/discussion-between-kiiv-and-deniz-da-king).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue might be in Upload log. There is mentioned `programmer = arduino` (in version before edit). That means you might be uploading code into the wrong Arduino. So there is no ArduinoISP sketch and it won't work (getsync() errors)

Check if the upload is working between two arduinos, that should opted out wrong wiring on the programmer side and so on.

And as it's self made board, there might be some issues with wiring, omitting bypass capacitors (as it turned out in chat discussion - it was the main issue)